# datagrip - schema name missing on console when opening a routine

Tags: datagrip, intellij-datagrip

I am new to datagrip client, I click on shift twice to open a search window, when I search for a routine (function or procedure) and press Enter, it opens the code in the console but the schema name is missing on the routine. 
Example: if the routine is

```
create or replace fuction testSchema.test_function() returns integer
{
// some code here
}
```

when I open that from the search window, it opens with function name only  (leaving the schema part) I searched in settings but unable to find any relevant one, by mistake if I compile this it's getting created in the public schema.

```
create or replace function test_function() returns integer
{
// some code here
}
```

can you please tell me how to configure this, so it also gives me schema name, 
I tried the short-cut from keymap in settings (CTRL + SHIFT +ALT + B) , but no luck.

Comment: Can you please describe why do you need this? If you edit the code just from here, it will be applied to the needed schema.

Comment: Thanks, it's working fine now.

Comment: When modifying and saving a function, without the original schema name attached, DataGrip will create that function to the public schema - so I end up with the old function in a custom schema and the new updated function in the public schema. Definitely not what I want. How did you make it work?

Comment: Do you still experience the issue in the latest DataGrip versions?